# Como ejecutar una agregación "lookup" con mongodb y node,js

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, agregación

Estoy tratando de relacionar dos colecciones en mongodb para simular un left outer join. Para ello uso agregaciones y el metodo "lookup". El resultado no es el esperado y no puedo ver que falla en mi sintaxis o logica. Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
//coleccion users
{
_id: ObjectId(1234566)
userName: "Juancho",
email: "juancho@gmail.com",
password: "123",
kids: [name:"juanchito", age:6]
}
```

```
//colección solicitudesDeNiñera

{
_id: ObjectId(656868),
requestedBy: "1234566" //este campo relaciona  a users mediante un id. En este caso el id del usuario Juancho,
date: 05/06/2021,
descroption: "solicito alguien que cuide a mis hijos por dos horas"
}
```

Quiero realizar una consulta que me devuelva los documentos de la colección "users" que esten relacionados con la colección "solicitudesDeNiñera". Para ello, escribí el siguiente codigo en node.js usando el API nativo de Mongo.

```
const joinedColleccions =  await client.db('wkkerpark').collection('users').aggregate([
         { 
       
        $lookup:{
            from: 'solicitudDeNiñera',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'requestedBy',
            as : 'solicitudesUsuarios'
        } }
        ]).toArray()
```

Lo que esperaría que me devolviera es lo siguiente:

```
[
{
_id: ObjectId(1234566)
userName: "Juancho",
email: "juancho@gmail.com",
password: "123",
kids: [name:"juanchito", age:6],

solicitudesUsuarios: [
{
 _id: ObjectId(656868),
requestedBy: "1234566" 
date: 05/06/2021,
descroption: "solicito alguien que cuide a mis hijos por dos horas"
}
]
}
]
```

Lo que en realidad recibo  es lo siguiente:

```
[
{
_id: ObjectId(1234566)
userName: "Juancho",
email: "juancho@gmail.com",
password: "123",
kids: [name:"juanchito", age:6],

solicitudesUsuarios:[] //este arreglo viene vacio.

}
]
```

Comment: I think you need to have the same type for `users` `_id` and `solicitudesDeNiñera` `requestedBy`.  In `users` it is `ObjectId`, but in `solicitudesDeNiñera` it is a string.  Maybe you want something like this [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_FpTCwdwD0- "Link to example -->") example?

Comment: I see what you mean. So I would have to insert reqestedBy as an ObjectId. I did not know that a single document could have two ObjectIds. I will give this a shot.

Comment: Up to the maximum size of a document, I think you can have as many `ObjectId`s as you want.  :-)

Comment: It worked! Thanks you are such a fine lad.

Comment: Glad to help!  Maybe you could answer your question below.  English is my primary language and I even struggle with that.  :-0